# Retornar arquivos Laravel Storage privado

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, storage

Bom dia,
tenho seguinte cenário:

1. Back Laravel API
2. Front Vuejs

Tenho um cadastro de formações de um cliente, onde posso colocar vários anexos (certificados).
Também é possível editar as formações existentes.
Tenho uma rota de API que retorna as informações da formação (Curso, instituição, ect) e queria retornar nessa mesma requisição os arquivos dessa formação, em formato 'File' para manipular no vuejs.

O storage não é publico, fica em storage/app/coach/formação.

Como retorno nessa requisição, dentro do objeto Formação, um array com os arquivos?

Tentei:

Opção 1
$documento = Storage::disk($destino)->get($doc->nome_documento)
array_push($array_documentos, ($file));

Opção 2
$nomeArquivo = pathinfo($doc->nome_documento, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$caminhoTemporario = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'laravel');
file_put_contents($caminhoTemporario, $documento);

$file = new UploadedFile($caminhoTemporario, $nomeArquivo);
array_push($array_documentos, ($file));

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Você precisa criar uma rota, e, nesta rota, acessar o arquivo. Não é possível fazer a requisição do arquivo fora da rota.
Exemplo: /controller/metodo/nomenoarquivo. Dentro deste, vc faz o uso do storage::disk, conforme documentação e dará certo. O segredo é só q precisa da rota.